# Set single tap and double tap actions in UITabBar in iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uigesturerecognizer, uitabbaritem

I am beginner in iOS app Develop. My problem is, To set different actions in single tab bar item, Single tap and double tap actions are need to be set tab bar item. Is this possible or any better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to achieve it with `UITabBar`. You'll need custom view as bar, and custom views on it as bar items, with added gesture recognizers for single and double tap

Comment: You're welcome. But it would be superb, if you'll mark my answer as the right one, upvote it

Comment: If I will get solution, Then i will vote for you. Now I tried long press gesture in tab bar item. No idea about custom views replace tab bar.